# Create a weekly line chart (52 labels)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to make a chart with label for each week in the year. I will be passing in an array with 52 data points. These data points are processed by the back-end so it is fine, however, typing out 52 labels is impractical.

```
var data = {
labels: ["Week 1", "Week 2", "week 3", ..., "week 52"],
datasets: [
    {
        data: [52 data points in here],
    }
]
};
```

How should I go about making these 52 labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option which may not be the best or most efficient is you could create a loop to make the Labels, if they will all have the same format:

```
var labels = [];
for(var i=1; i<=52; i++) {
    labels.push("Week " + i);
}
```

Comment: ended up doing something similar to this with Carbon.